# VBS: Rename and move files to subfolders

Tags: vbscript, wsh

having some problems by renaming and moving files within a folder to some subfolders.

The files have the following name structure like
 *WATERFALLS=Mills Creek.jpg* or *ANIMALS=Timber Wolfes.jpg*
how can I move those two files to two (new) subfolders named
*WATERFALLS* and *ANIMALS* by renaming the files into new names (after the equal signs) like Mills Creek.jpg and *Timber Wolfes.jpg*.
Perhaps a protocol file maybe written too.

I'm very new to VBS and I like to have a solution.

Many thanks in advance

With sunday regards

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Start your research with the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Use [Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to split the file names into the folder and file name part:

```
>> s = "WATERFALLS=Mills Creek.jpg"
>> a = Split(s, "=")
>> WScript.Echo a(0)
>> WScript.Echo a(1)
>>
WATERFALLS
Mills Creek.jpg
```

To access/manipulate elements of the file system, use the methods of the [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). To get the list of files in your source folders, use the .Files collection of a folder object (cf. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz72a8c0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)). Your tasks - checking for existence of folders/files, creating folders, moving files - can be done with suitably named methods: [.FolderExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xc78d8d%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [.FileExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [.CreateFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kby5ae3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), and [.MoveFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcf3ba6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).